# Drop all columns before a particular column (by name) in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I found a bunch of answers about how to drop columns using index numbers.

I am stumped about how to drop all columns after a particular column by name.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','C','D'])
df.drop(['B':],inplace=True)
```

I expect the new `df` to have only `A B` columns.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Dropping all columns *after* is the same as keeping all columns up to and including.  So:

```
In [321]: df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','C','D'])

In [322]: df = df.loc[:, :'B']

In [323]: df
Out[323]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B]
Index: []
```

(Using `inplace` is typically not worth it.)

Comment: @piRSquared: no, it doesn't.  If the columns were ["C", "B", "A", "D"], `:, :"B"` selects all columns up to and including B.  And in the case of non-uniqueness, you get a nice error message.

Comment: Worked perfectly and exactly what I was looking for. The list approach is something I considered but thought there must be a better way. Thanks

Comment: right!  The issue I was thinking of is that it will not give columns `['A', 'B']` unless previously sorted.  But it will give all columns up to and including `'B'`.  That was a brain fart on my part.

Comment: @DSM I just tried to reverse it, that is select upto certain column, somehow I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 5):

#### `get_loc` and `iloc`

Dropping some is the same as selecting the others.

```
df.iloc[:, :df.columns.get_loc('B') + 1]

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B]
Index: []
```

Comment: Awesome this worked very well! I was having an issue with the accepted answer, I would get an IndexingError: Too many indexers, but your solution worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
df.drop(df.columns[list(df.columns).index("B")+1:],inplace=True)
```

Comment: note I added a list(df.columns) instead of just df.columns

Answer (score 0):

df = df[df.columns[:list(df.columns).index('B')+1]]

should work.